# Convert html to doc in java

Tags: java, html, xhtml, docx, doc

I would like to convert either an html or xhtml document (preferably with styles) to Microsoft .doc and/or .docx format.

There seem to be plenty of examples for doing this the other way around but I haven't found any useful examples for converting to ms document formats.

Can anyone point me to an api or provide an example for doing this please

Many thanks

Comment: do you want to have an actual .doc file or a file that can be opened with word and/or modified/printed?

Comment: actual doc or docx. It looks like it would probably be easier to create a docx but doc would provide better backwards compatability

Comment: There could be something in open/libre office to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

docx4j 2.8.0 supports converting XHTML documents and fragments to docx content.  Disclosure: I wrote some of the code.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more information... i'm very keen to know how to do this

Comment: The blog post http://www.docx4java.org/blog/2012/05/docx4j-2-8-0-released/ contains links to sample code.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another solution would be to use [jodconverter](http://www.artofsolving.com/opensource/jodconverter/guide/supportedformats) which seems to basic html to doc conversion... it doesn't claim to do it well though

Comment: Is you find anything which convert both doc and docx into html? Please show me sample code if any?

Comment: I haven't been able to commit myself to this yet i'm afraid

Answer (score 1):

I tried docjx4j API 2.8.1 and it works like wonder. It had ConvertinXHTMLinFile and it works fine. If anyone wants the code I will post it.

Here is the link that helped me : [ConvertInXHTMLFile](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j-ImportXHTML/blob/master/src/samples/java/org/docx4j/samples/ConvertInXHTMLFile.java)

Answer (score 0):

In order to work with Microsoft Documents you'll likely have to take a deeper look at [Apache's POI Library](http://poi.apache.org/).

Nevertheless creating .doc files with styling from (X)HTML requires some effort.

Comment: Indeed, Apache POI is pretty much the only port of call. It doesn't do the conversion (which is very, very far from trivial), but it does allow you to create .doc documents.

Comment: I'm after something that will do the donkey work for me really. Something that will parse and xhtml document and output a doc or docx document

Answer (score 0):

I've been spending a little time looking into [docx4j](http://dev.plutext.org/svn/docx4j/trunk/docx4j/docs/Docx4j_GettingStarted.html). It seems to provide nice ways for creating html documents from docx but I can't see anything for the other way round.

At the moment this is still looking like the easiest method as it's just working with jaxb objects (I think).

Comment: I have converted docx4j's HTML (as opposed to any old bit of HTML) back to docx. As a result there is a little stuff in docx4j to help you: classes such as org.docx4j.model.properties.run.Bold have constructors which take a CSSValue. Other bits aren't there (eg the code which uses that, the code for converting an HTML table, and the code to import an image).