# Convert HTML/MXML file to Word doc programmatically in Java

Tags: java, html, mxml, docx

I would like to convert either an HTML or MXML file document to Microsoft .doc and/or .docx format.

Please  provide an example for doing this?

Comment: exact clone of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5403356/convert-html-to-doc-in-java

Comment: @Fedor Skrynnikov : the answer in that question is not accepted, and r confusing

Comment: This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203174/whats-a-good-java-api-for-creating-word-documents can help you choose a good one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've found that by far the best (free) option to do conversions like this is to use the OpenOffice API. It has a very robust conversion facility. It's a bit of a pain to initially get working because of how abstract the API is, but once you do, it's powerful. [This API wrapper](http://www.artofsolving.com/opensource/jodconverter) helps to simplify it somewhat.

Comment: A maintained fork of the wrapper https://github.com/sbraconnier/jodconverter/

Answer (score 5):

You can also use [docx4j.jar](http://www.docx4java.org/downloads.html) which simply converts xhtml to docx.

You can save your format information as xhtml template and place input from form (like name,age,address etc) into the template at runtime.

This is a sample code to refer from this [link](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j-ImportXHTML/blob/master/src/samples/java/org/docx4j/samples/XhtmlToDocxAndBack.java)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
 {
        String xhtml= 
                "<table border=\"1\" cellpadding=\"1\" cellspacing=\"1\" style=\"width:100%;\"><tbody><tr><td>test</td><td>test</td></tr><tr><td>test</td><td>test</td></tr><tr><td>test</td><td>test</td></tr></tbody></table>";       

        // To docx, with content controls
        WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.createPackage();

        XHTMLImporterImpl XHTMLImporter = new XHTMLImporterImpl(wordMLPackage);

        wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().getContent().addAll( 
                XHTMLImporter.convert( xhtml, null) );

        wordMLPackage.save(new java.io.File("D://sample.docx"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use both iText and Apache POI to handle and convert MS doc in Java.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert HTML to DOCX using Aspose.Words Cloud SDK for Java. Its free pricing plan offers 150 free API calls per month.

P.S: I am a developer evangelist at Aspose

```
//Get Client ID and Client Key from https://dashboard.aspose.cloud/
WordsApi wordsApi = new WordsApi("xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx","xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","https://api.aspose.cloud");
ApiClient client = wordsApi.getApiClient();
client.setConnectTimeout(12*60*1000);
client.setReadTimeout(12*60*1000);
client.setWriteTimeout(12*60*1000);
try {
    
    ConvertDocumentRequest request = new ConvertDocumentRequest(
            Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("C:/Temp/02_pages.html").toAbsolutePath()),
            "docx",
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null
        );

        File result = wordsApi.convertDocument(request);
        System.out.println("api request completed...");
        File dest = new File("C:/Temp/02_pages_java.docx");
        Files.copy(result.toPath(), dest.toPath(),
        java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
```